# Where can I find an example of a propulsion maintenance task card?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, propulsion

I'm looking for an example of a [task card](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/69/62) for aircraft propulsion maintenance, e.g. propeller or engine maintenance. I've found examples for wings and airframes, but not for propulsion.

Comment: Why are you looking for such a thing (what underlying question do you have that a *powerplant* card could answer, but not an *airframe* card)?

Answer (score 0):

This should be within the scope of Maintenance Manual.
The Job Task to perform are usually referenced to particular task of the engine in the Engine Maintenance Manual.